# jQuery can only use value after alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I wasn't really sure what to look for concerning this, google hasn't brought me a lot of results but it could be I'm searching for the wrong thing.

I'm currently writing an application making use of jQuery cookie plugin. For the most part it's working ok. I have a piece of code that isn't working 100%

```
    var name = $.cookie('appview');
    this.changeStateToViewing( name );
```

This doesn't work. I've also tried `name = name + ""` and `name.toString()` and `String(name)`.

There are only two ways I can get the value of `appview` in my program.

- When I use the alert function to print the value of `appview`, it works
- When I debug the program and look at `appview` in the expressions it works

If I just let the program run, there is no result.

[image]
[image]
But when I use an alert

[image]
[image]
I'm not sure what's going on. I'm using Firefox.

Here's the example code I have

```
Application.prototype.changeStateToViewing = function( name ) {
    this.setViewing(name);
    this.viewingDiv.fadeIn( 250, function(){} );
    this.gitDiv.fadeIn( 250, function(){} );
    this.markdownDiv.fadeIn( 250, function(){} );
    this.appState = EApplicationState.VIEWING;
    $.cookie('appstate', 'viewing');
    $.cookie('appview', name);
}

Application.prototype.setViewing = function( name ) {
    $("#viewingusername").text(name);
}
```

EDIT: I've notice `$('#viewingusername').text("LKDSJFDSJFLKJDSLKFJDSLKFj")` doesn't work after refreshing the browser, timing problem?

Comment: Could throw together a fiddle?

Comment: Where do you set the `Bryan` text, maybe there's something wrong there? Have you tried setting the text value to something static?

Comment: I set the text `bryan` via `$.cookie`: `$.cookie('appview', name);`. I just tried static text as well which isn't working either, so I'm thinking my problem is something different actually.

Comment: console.log confirmed the value is being sent: http://i.imgur.com/tN6GpSS.png it's just not being updated

Comment: @BryanAbrams , you got answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that you have stored too many cookie. you can clear the cookie and retry this. and workaround could be setting `setTimeout` with some delay(however it is bad practice as we still do not know how time is it going to get the cookie).

```
var name = $.cookie('appview');
setTimeout(function(){
    this.changeStateToViewing(name); 
},500)
```

Comment: I've cleared my cookies and I'm only using 2 different ones in in my code. This solution didn't work for me.